# Checking login status before wp_get_current_user is initialised

Tags: hooks

I am building a theme switcher, that needs to block access to not logged in and subscriber users. Problem is that this has to be done in a function that is called at the "setup_theme" phase/hook, and wp_get_current_user etc. is not yet available at that point.

Is there a workaround to check if someone is logged in at this pre-init phase, and what the capabilities of this person are?

Regards,
Joost.

Comment: Are you sure? I just called `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();` on a setup_theme action and it returned all the current user info.

Comment: You are right. The problem was a change in the wp-config.php that redirected to the main domain. I tried to log in on the subdomain and was subsequently redirected to the main domain. 
So the script was right. I was not logged in and it rightly denied me acces :-)

Thanks for your help.